# jquery range slider max text value

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
 jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      step: 1,
      values: [ 2, 3 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( addCommas(ui.values[ 0 ]) + " - " + addCommas(ui.values[ 1 ]) + ',-' );
      }
    });
```

Is it possible to set the maximum value as a text? So values would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,some text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check it in the `slide` function, like so:

```
var maxValue = 10;
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: maxValue,
      step: 1,
      values: [ 2, 3 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var maxDisplayed = ( ui.values[1] == maxValue ? "max" : ui.values[1]);
        $( "#amount" ).val( addCommas(ui.values[ 0 ]) + " - " + addCommas(maxDisplayed) + ',-' );
      }
    });
```